# Moving files to trashbin

Tags: powershell

I have a direct delete function (deletes the files direct) implemented in my script, and a trashbin delete function (moving it to the trashbin first).

The problem is that the trashbin delete doesn't work. I've tried [this suggested post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502002/how-do-i-move-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin-using-powershell) already but it doesn't seem to work.

My full script :

```
## Top of the script
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateRange(0,99999)]
    [int]$minutes,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
    [string]$maplocation,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet("Direct", "TrashBin")]
    [string]$consequence
)

## error notifications

## Variables
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $maplocation | Get-Date
$time = Get-Date
$minutesconvert = (New-Timespan -Start $file -End $time).TotalMinutes

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    if ($minutes -lt $minutesconvert -and $consequence -eq "direct")
    {
        Write-Verbose "File Found $file" -Verbose
        Write-Verbose "Deleting $file" -Verbose
        Remove-Item $file.FullName
    }
    elseif ($minutes -lt $minutesconvert -and $consequence -eq "trashbin")
    {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::DeleteFile($maplocation, 'OnlyErrorDialogs', 'SendToRecycleBin')
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Verbose -message  "txt" -verbose
    }
}

Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::DeleteFile($maplocation, 'OnlyErrorDialogs', 'SendToRecycleBin')
```

Error code in PowerShell console:

```
New-TimeSpan : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.DateTime' required
by parameter 'Start'. The method is not supported.
At C:\Users\david\Desktop\nieuw.ps1:21 char:39
+ $minutesconvert = (New-TimeSpan -Start <<<<  $file -End $time).TotalMinutes
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-TimeSpan], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewTimeSpanCommand
```

Comment: have you tried the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/503768/1163423)?

Comment: Please provide more detail than "doesn't work". What happens? Errors? File deleted completely?

Comment: Change `$maplocation = "C:\Temp"`

Comment: @JamesC. My bad was a typo of me.

Comment: It's still wrong, you need quotes around the path.

Comment: Ok another typo. You can trust on me that the location is correct. Error code is provided in OP.

Comment: @MartinBrandl Yes accepted answer doesn't work aswell since it will open a message prompt which something like "are you sure you want to move this file to the trashbin". I need it done silently

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It gives an error code provided in the OP. File is not deleted

Comment: Your error is coming from line 23 `New-TimeSpan` but you don't call this in the code you've provided and it's certainly not 23 lines long either. Can you provide the full script you're running?

Comment: That error is not related to the code you've posted. Please post the actual code you're executing

Comment: @JamesC.  yes added in  the OP .

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added the full code in the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your culprit:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $maplocation | Get-Date
```

The above statement will give you the current date and time for each file and folder in `$maplocation`. If `$maplocation` is not a single file the result is an array, which `New-TimeSpan` is not prepared to handle. The procedure is also very unlikely to be what you actually intended. You probably want the time difference between the last modification (creation) date of `$maplocation` (or its contents?). Besides, rather than calculating a timespan it's better to subtract the number of minutes from the current timestamp and use that as a reference date.

Also, depending on what you want to do in case `$maplocation` is a folder, you may need to process the item differently:

- `$maplocation` is a folder and you want to delete the folder and everything in it, or `$maplocation` is a single file:

  ```
  $maxAge = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$minutes)
  $file   = Get-Item $maplocation
  if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt $maxAge) {
    switch ($consequence) {
      'direct'   { ... }
      'trashbin' { ... }
    }
  }
  ```
- `$maplocation` is a folder and you want to delete only items from it that are older than the reference date:

  ```
  $maxAge = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$minutes)
  $files  = Get-ChildItem $maplocation -Recurse
  foreach ($file in $files) {
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt $maxAge) {
      switch ($consequence) {
        'direct'   { ... }
        'trashbin' { ... }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Since the sample code from your question is incomplete further adjustments may be required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you helped me a lot.