# How can I implement Deleting files to the Recycle bin rather than Permanently deleting?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a server that continues to close the gap on our D: Storage. So, from time to time I go into the location and manually delete files to free some space "Yuck". I have created a simple Powershell script that allows me to configure which files specifically and the dates (this is important) that need to be removed. Unfortunately during my testing, I soon realized the files are permanently deleted and I would rather have them sent to the Trash bin.

Here is the code:

```
   Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\Temp\TWLogTest\*.* | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt (get-date "12-03- 2016 01:00AM") -and $_.
   CreationTime -lt (get-date "10-10-2019 14:00PM")} | Where-Object {$_.name -match "tomcat"} | Remove-Items
```

Any help, guidance or ideas with implementing a Delete into this specific script would be greatly appreciated. I have looked at Module-Recycle, but still not sure how to add it here.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: But if the goal is to free disk space, recycling won't help.

Comment: This is true and thanks for your input, I figured it would free space on that specific drive and allow flexibility in case of deleting the wrong file. These are application logs they may hold data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on here:  [How do I move a file to the Recycle Bin using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502002/how-do-i-move-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin-using-powershell)

```
using assembly microsoft.visualbasic
using namespace microsoft.visualbasic

[FileIO.FileSystem]::DeleteFile('foo.txt', 'OnlyErrorDialogs', 'SendToRecycleBin')
```

Something like this should match your code.  That method only works on files.  When comparing dates, the 2nd argument will get cast to [datetime] anyway.

```
using assembly microsoft.visualbasic
using namespace microsoft.visualbasic

Dir -File -R C:\Temp\TWLogTest | Where { 
  $_.CreationTime -gt '12/3/16 1AM' -and 
  $_.CreationTime -lt '10/10/19 2PM' -and 
  $_.name -match 'tomcat' } | 
foreach { [FileIO.FileSystem]::DeleteFile($_.fullname, 'OnlyErrorDialogs',
  'SendToRecycleBin') }
```

Comment: Right, I have seen this solution and it probably works well with short file names, the problem is the data logs have long names and dates attached to them... I cannot use 'foo.txt' (i get it as an example) because the file names require more specificity. This is why I used " -match 'tomcat' " because tomcat is a word within certain files I need to remove.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Awesome stuff, thanks for the helpful implementation !